# cyclic Include dependency causing trouble, how to solve?

Tags: c, include

I got 2 header files which need(?) to include each other.

The first one

> header1.h

looks like this:

```
#ifndef HEADER1_H
#define HEADER1_H

#include "header2.h"

typedef Needed_s
{
     size_t something;
} Needed_t;

typedef partialstruct_s
{
     size_t something;
     Needed_t *pointer;
} partialstruct_t;

void function (MyStruct_t Parameter);//<- this line gets the error

#endif
```

The second one

> header2.h

like this:

```
#ifndef HEADER2_H
#define HEADER2_H

#include "header1.h"

typedef MyStruct_s
{
     //struct partialstruct_s ThisOne;
     //I tryed both ways!
     partialstruct_t ThisOne;
} MyStruct_t;

#endif
```

I dont like this way of working, but I also don't like to declare structures in different headers where they contend related don't belong to.

The code is just a MCTR so please don't give me improvement hints.

I now get the error:

> header1.h:17: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'MyStruct_t '

So is this problem caused by the include dependency? And if so, how could I solve it?

Comment: If two headers/libraries/modules/whatever mutually depend on one another, it's probably a mistake for them to be separate to begin with.

Comment: But some times the intent of their use is thematicaly absolutly different. And in the view of clean code, this is not a mistake to also watch this thematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler error you are getting is simply a result of including `header2.h` in a .c file.  That will go through roughly the following steps

1. defines `HEADER2_H`
2. includes `header1.h`
3. defines `HEADER1_H`
4. includes `header2.h` but because `HEADER2_H` is already defined this is largely a no-op
5. Now back in `header1.h` the compiler encounters `void function (MyStruct_t Parameter);`

At this point `MyStruct_t` isn't defined because `header2.h` hasn't been processed yet hence you get the specified compiler error.

Unfortunately there is really no way to have this solved with the code in the header files as defined because of the cyclic dependency.

- `header1.h` depends on the full implementation of `MyStruct_t` which is in `header2.h`
- `header2.h` depends on the full implementation of `partialstruct_t` which is is `header1.h`

In order to fix this you will either need to switch one of the header files to use a pointer or create a third header file, `header0.`h which contains the definition of `partialstruct_t`

Comment: excluding partialstruct_t into another header file didn't solved it for me :/

Comment: @Zaibis did you update the include order to reflcet the new breakdown?

Comment: @Zaibis both header2 should include header0, header1 should include header0, and header2.  header0 will need a forward declaration of `Nested` though

Comment: well I just putted all typedefs into header1 now and made in header2 a out commented typedef of them with the note where to find them and that it wasn't possible in a different way. Thanks for your help anyway.